# Ajax call is not working on check box change function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am trying to do an ajax call on check box check.

Here is my code:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EmsAdmin.Models.User>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="EmsAdmin.Models" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
alert("I am here");
var manuId = ('#value');
alert(manuId);

$('#value:checkbox').change(function () {
    var taskInput;
    alert("I am here" +'#<%: Model.ManufacturerId %>');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ReportUserVerification/GetCountriesForManufacturer/<%:Model.ManufacturerId%>",

        type:'get',
        success: function (data) {
            taskInput = data;
            var countriesArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var item1 = data[i];
                alert(item1);
                if (item1 != null) {
                    countriesArray.push(item1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

//]]>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
alert("I am here");
var manuId = ('#value');
alert(manuId);

  $('#value').change(function () {
    var taskInput;
    alert("I am here" +'#<%: Model.ManufacturerId %>');
    $.ajax({
        url:
    "/ReportUserVerification/GetCountriesForManufacturer/<%:Model.ManufacturerId%>",

        type:'get',
        success: function (data) {
            taskInput = data;
            var countriesArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var item1 = data[i];
                alert(item1);
                if (item1 != null) {
                    countriesArray.push(item1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

//]]>
</script>

<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Edit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try 
 again.") %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
 {%>
 <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
<p>
<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Id,"Id:") %>
<%: Model.Id %>
</p>
<p>
<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.PersonId,"Person:") %>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.PersonId, (SelectList)ViewData["allPersons"], "Select 
 person", new { @style = "width: 255px;" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Person,"") %>
</p>
 <p>
<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Email,"Email:") %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Email, new { @style = "width:250px;" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Email,"") %>
</p>
<p>
<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Corporation.Description,"Corporation:") %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Corporation.Description, new { @style = "width:250px;" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Corporation.Description,"") %>
</p>
<hr />
<h2>
 Approve User</h2>
 <p>
 <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Approve,"Aprrove User:") %>
  <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(e=> e.Approve,Model.Approve) %><span>&nbsp;Switch this on if you 
 want to
    add regitrar </span>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Approve,"") %>
</p>
```

---

### Multi Select Brands If Required:

```
  <div id ="ManufacturerId"<%:Model.ManufacturerDescription %>>
  <p>
     <%= Html.LabelFor(e=> e.ManufacturerDescription,"Brand:") %>  
    <br/>
 </p>

  <%for (int i = 0; i < Model.Manufacturers.Count;i++ )
  {%>
  <p>
                 <%:Html.HiddenFor(e=>e.Manufacturers[i].Id) %>
        <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Manufacturers[i].IsSelected) %>
         <%:Html.LabelFor(x => x.CountryNames[i].IsSelected, 
    Model.Manufacturers[i].Description)%>
          </p>

  <%} %>
  </div>
  <%--<p>
  <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.ManufacturerDescription,"Brand:") %>
  <%= Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.ManufacturerDescription, 
  (SelectList)ViewData["allManufacturers"], "Select  Brands", new { @style = "width:

    255px;" })%>
   <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.ManufacturerDescription,"") %>

</p>


<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.CountryName,"Country:") %>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.CountryName, (SelectList)ViewData["allCountries"], 
"Select Countries", new { @style = "width: 255px;" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.CountryName,"") %>
</p>--%>

<hr />
 <h2>
 Select Role:</h2>
 <p>
 <%= Html.LabelFor(e => e.Role, "Role:")%>
 <%= Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Role, (SelectList)ViewData["allRoles"], "Select 
  Roles",
 new { @style = "width: 255px;" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Role,"") %>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
<%= Html.ActionLink("Cancel","Details",new {id=Model.Id},new {@title="exit without 
 saving"}) %>
 </p>
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, at each iteration of `for` loop you are generating `div` with the same id. It is illegal in HTML to have several elements with the same id on the page, and javascript behavior in this case could be really unpredictable.

At second, `$('#value')` selects only element with `id="value"`, which is div. div does not raise `change` event if some of its content has changed. To handle selection changes of the checkbox, you need to adjust the selector to query the checkbox itself. For example, like this:

```
$('#value :checkbox').change(function () {
```

Comment: @Andrie I am wondering how will I get current selected value?

Comment: @62071072, removing `div` completely is not a good solution here, cause it makes it harder to query the check box in question. Better approach would be to turn its id into class (if it is possible), something like `<div class="value"`. Then you can query checkboxes with `$('.value :checkbox')`. As to current selected value - you can use `$(this).val()` inside the handler.

Comment: That didnt work I mean on alert of $(this).val() it is not returning any value.